# node.JS how to read Idp metadata from XML file using passport-saml?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml

I am trying to configure passport-saml node.js, but I do not know how to read the idp metadata.

this is my passport.js file:

```
passport.use(
new SamlStrategy(
    {
        path: '/login/callback',
        entryPoint: "/entrypoint", //specific for my integration
        issuer: 'passport-saml',
        protocol: "http://",
        cert: 'fake cert', // cert must be provided
        logoutUrl: "/ "
    },
  function(profile, done) {
    findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
)
)
```

My metadata is in a XML file.

Do I need to configure it with [passport-saml-metadata](https://github.com/compwright/passport-saml-metadata#readme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this useful tutorial on how to configure SAML in node.JS:
https://dev.to/miteshkamat27/sso-express-js-passport-saml-3b6c